# Sitecore 8 Update 4 Missing layout templates

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I upgraded my sitecore site from Sitecore 7.5 to sitecore 8 update 4 at the end when trying to browse the site using the web database I have an error indicate that the layout can not be found.

I checked sitecore and I found that the layout templates are not exist in web database but exist in master.

Any suggestion on why this happened and How to fix it?

Comment: You should check Publishing Restrictions and Workflow State of that layout items and their ancestors. Try to force republish of your Layouts node.

Comment: I tried but with no luck, I don't know what is the cause but I solved it by moving the items from master to web using control panel option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by moving (copying) the layouts template form master to web using control panel database option ( Move item ).